# My code is looping short as i inserting rows in middle of the code running

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

At the start of the code the last row is 46. But while running the code I am inserting sum rows in between, so the last row becomes 53. But code ends after 46 rows.. I want to run the code till last rows (53 rows)

```
Sub sman90_Days()

  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

  Dim L As Long
  For L = 5 To Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Row

  If Range("B" & L).Value <> Empty Then
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim sqlstr As String
    sqlstr = "select Sum(InvAmt-Ramt),Jv_SubAc_cd from tbFn_CusAge('HO','" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "','0') where JV_AcCd in ('" & Range("B" & L).Value & "')and InvAge between '90' and '120' Group by Jv_SubAc_cd"

    ' Create the connection string.
    'sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=INSTANCE\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=NaranjeeDB;" & _
                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=NHDBSERVER;Database=NaranjeeDB;User Id=sa;Password=befrank;ConnenctionTimout=300;"

    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    'rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString

    'rs.Open conn.Execute("select Sum(InvAmt-Ramt),Jv_SubAc_cd from tbFn_CusAge('HO','" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "','0') where JV_AcCd in ('" & Range("B" & L).Value & "')and InvAge between '90' and '120' Group by Jv_SubAc_cd "), DBCOunt
    rs.Open sqlstr, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

    ' Check we have data.
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' Transfer result.
        If rs.RecordCount < sh.Range(("K" & L), sh.Range("K" & L).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count - 2 Then
            Range("K" & L).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
        Else
            Range("K" & L).EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rs.RecordCount).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Range("K" & L).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
         End If

    ' Close the recordset
        rs.Close
    Else
        'MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
        'Exit Sub
    End If
   End If
   Next

    ' Clean up
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

'Call sman120_Days
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

- Best way to deal with this situation is to Run a Loop Backwards. But in this situation,it seemed a little tricky to me, so i did a workaround.
- Also you should Indent your code properly. As whenever the code gets lengthy, it becomes quite difficult to understand.

**Basically change the Loop like this:**

```
Dim L As Long, lr As Long, lrr As Long

lr = Range("B100000").End(xlUp).row
lrr = 5

Here:
For L = lrr To lr
```

**And recalculate `lr` at the End of Loop before your `Next`**

```
lr = Range("B100000").End(xlUp).row
lrr = L + 1
GoTo Here
```

---

**Try:**

```
Sub sman90_Days()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim L As Long, lr As Long, lrr As Long

lr = Range("B100000").End(xlUp).row
lrr = 5

Here:
For L = lrr To lr

If Range("B" & L).Value <> Empty Then


    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim sqlstr As String

    sqlstr = "select Sum(InvAmt-Ramt),Jv_SubAc_cd from tbFn_CusAge('HO','" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "','0') where JV_AcCd in ('" & Range("B" & L).Value & "')and InvAge between '90' and '120' Group by Jv_SubAc_cd"

    ' Create the connection string.
    'sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=INSTANCE\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=NaranjeeDB;" & _
                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=NHDBSERVER;Database=NaranjeeDB;User Id=sa;Password=befrank;ConnenctionTimout=300;"

    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    'rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic


    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString

    'rs.Open conn.Execute("select Sum(InvAmt-Ramt),Jv_SubAc_cd from tbFn_CusAge('HO','" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "','0') where JV_AcCd in ('" & Range("B" & L).Value & "')and InvAge between '90' and '120' Group by Jv_SubAc_cd "), DBCOunt
    rs.Open sqlstr, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText



    ' Check we have data.
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' Transfer result.
        If rs.RecordCount < sh.Range(("K" & L), sh.Range("K" & L).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count - 2 Then


            Range("K" & L).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
        Else
            Range("K" & L).EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rs.RecordCount).Insert Shift:=xlDown

            Range("K" & L).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs

         End If

    ' Close the recordset
        rs.Close
    Else
        'MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
        'Exit Sub
    End If

   Else

   End If

   lr = Range("B100000").End(xlUp).row
   lrr = L + 1
   GoTo Here

Next

    ' Clean up
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

'Call sman120_Days
End Sub
```